# How to schedule daily push notifications in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7, ios8

I want my app to notify the user everyday at 13pm. I put this inside my app delegate:

```
    func Notification() {
    var Notification = UILocalNotification()
    Notification.alertAction = "New Question!"
    Notification.alertBody = "Solve the new question!"


    Notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(Notification)
}
```

and this inside my application didFinishLaunching:

```
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, categories: nil))
```

What do I have to do so that my notification is scheduled to fire daily?

Answer (score 0):

just set any past date that at 13pm,
and set repeatInterval as `.CalendarUnitDay`

```
let startDate = Date()
var component = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: Date())
component.hour = 13
let fireDate = Calendar.current.date(from: component)

notification.repeatInterval = .day;
notification.fireDate = fireDate
```

Update:

```
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: component, repeats: true)
var triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second], from: Date())
triggerDaily.hour = 13
triggerDaily.minute = 0
triggerDaily.second = 0
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "title"
content.body = "body"
content.categoryIdentifier = "todoList"

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in // to do }
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your procedure.

Comment: Could you explain it better to me? Thanks

Comment: Note that UILocalNotification has been depreciated.